# Filter uncategorized tests in vstest.console.exe

Tags: vstest, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

I have a visual studio test assembly. There are several test methods of which a few methods have `TestCategoryAttribute` on them and others don't. I want to filter out all the methods that do not contain the attribute from getting executed, i.e, uncategorized tests should not be executed.

I am trying to have something like this which does not work.
`vstest.console.exe MyTests.dll /TestCaseFilter:"(TestCategory!=)"`

Looking for the right syntax. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I'd like to rely on this kind of filter as well.

Comment: I did not find the right way of doing it. I managed to filter-out all the categorized test cases like this. `TestCaseFilter:(TestCategory!=Category1&TestCategory!=Category2&TestCategory!=Category3)`

Comment: Thanks for the update @Kannan. Unfortunately, that would be prohibitively complex in my case as we have at least 15 different categories and this list is growing consistently over time :S